# how to put a constraint while solving nonlinear equations using "nleqslv" package in R

Tags: r

I need to solve the following nonlinear equation to get the value of (sd.1.est).
(k)and (R.bar) are known values calculated from a previous step. this is my code:

```
library(nleqslv) 
k=0.7642437
R.bar=0.4419803
sd=1.109488
fun <- function(sd.1.est){
(-(k^2)/(2*(sd.1.est^2)))+log((k/sd.1.est)+
(((k/sd.1.est)^3)*factorial(3)/((factorial(1))^2*(factorial(2))*(2^3)))+
(((k/sd.1.est)^5)*factorial(5)/((factorial(2))^2*(factorial(3))*(2^6)))+
(((k/sd.1.est)^7)*factorial(7)/((factorial(3))^2*(factorial(4))*(2^9))))-log(4*R.bar/sqrt(2*pi))}
ss1=nleqslv(sd,fun,method="Broyden",global="qline",control=list(cndtol=10^-12,maxit=1000,allowSingular =TRUE))
```

I need to put a constraint on sd.1.est to be positive ( as it is an estimate for the scale parameter).
I do not know how to write this.

Comment: You should give a complete reproducible example.  We don't have `k` or `R.bar`, and you didn't say what package contains `nleqslv`.  I'd guess it's from the `nleqslv` package and can add `library(nleqslv)`, but then when I try your code I get a syntax error.  Try to make it easier to help you!

Answer (score 0):

We cannot run your code since you have not provided any data.
In other words your code is not reproducible.

There is a way to get yourself a positive value for `sd.1.est` by a change of variable.
Write the header of your function as follows:

```
fun <- function(z) {
    sd.1.est <- z*z
    ........
}
```

Here `z` is an intermediate variable. By squaring `z` and assigning the result  to `sd.1.est` you will always get a positive value for `sd.1.est`.

In the call to `nleqslv` the initial value for `z` should be set to the `sqrt` of your initial value `sd`.

**Warning: this may not work.**

Comment: Thanks alot, got it